# About the subspace of polynomial vector space

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Why the set of functions in $C\left [ 1,-1 \right ]$ such that $f\left ( -1 \right )= f\left ( 1 \right )$ is the subspace of $C\left [ 1,-1 \right ]$?

Comment: Because it satisfies all the axioms for vector subspaces.

Answer (score 3):

Simply we have:

- The zero function lies in this set
- $$(\lambda f+\mu g)(1)=(\lambda f+\mu g)(-1)$$
  whenever $f$ and $g$ are two functions of this set and $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is the kernel of the linear map $C[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$, $f\mapsto f(1)-f(-1)$.